# При GET запросе на сервер получаю ошибку 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, http-status-code-500

Получаю ошибку 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR) при запросе к серверу. Раньше все было ок.
Первая версия приложения была с локальным бэкендом, сейчас же бэк вынесли на swagger. Теперь получать данные через API мы можем только с сервера. У меня есть метод который дергает экшен из store.js для получения данных. Не могу понять что не так с запросом. Подскажите пожалуйста.

**Метод, который дергает метод из vuex.**

```
async setDirection(value) {
  if (value) {
    this.selectedDirection = value;
  }
  let shit = 0;
  clearInterval(this.intervalTimerId);
  this.intervalTimerId = setInterval(async () => {
    try {
      const result = await this.$store.dispatch(
        "getQaStructs_actions",
        this.requestParams
      );
      if (result) {
        shit++;
        if (shit === 1) {
          this.chartData = result[0].chart;
        }
        this.tableData = result[0].table;
        if (!this.max_slippage) {
          this.max_slippage = result[0].max_slippage;
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("catch", error);
    }
  }, 2000);

  /*       console.log("tableData", this.tableData); */
},
```

**store.js**

```
async getQaStructs_actions(context, params) {
  try {
    let query = {
      currency: context.rootState.calculator.selectedUnderlying,
      maturity: context.rootState.calculator.selectedMaturity,
      amount: context.rootState.calculator.coinAmount,
      fut_hedge_flag: params.fut_hedge_flag,
      main_direction: params.main_direction,
      main_range: `[${
        Array.isArray(params.main_range)
          ? params.main_range.join(",")
          : params.main_range
      }]`,
      sub_direction_flag: params.sub_direction_flag,
      sub_range: `[${
        Array.isArray(params.sub_range)
          ? params.sub_range.join(",")
          : params.sub_range
      }]`,
      max_slippage: params.max_slippage,
    };

    const url = `data/qaStructs?${Object.entries(query)
      .map((r) => `${r[0]}=${r[1]}`)
      .join("&")}`;
    let response = await axios.get(url);
    return response.data.data;
  } catch (error) {
    return false;
  }
},
```

**Тот самый swagger (внешний API)**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Статус 500+ как бы намекает, что проблема не со стороны запроса

Comment: У меня было предположение, что я не правильно делаю запрос на сервер. В swagger есть параметры которые я не передаю. Имеет место такая теория ?

Comment: Попробуйте выполнить тот же запрос, только через сваггер, там скорее всего тоже будет ошибка 500. Стоит обратиться к тому, кто писал бэк и узнать, что является причиной поломки.

Comment: @yOz вам стоит почитать значения статусов, к примеру на википедии той же. Если коротко, то при неправильном запросе вам выдаст какой то из 400х с дополнительными пояснениями. Если выдается 500+, то это уже ошибка на стороне бэкенда однозначно.